# Python : class definition with **kwargs

Tags: python, oop, instance

When trying to instantiate the following class I am getting the following error :

```
"TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"
```

Do you know what would be the issue ? Here is the class definition :

```
class db_create_table():
        '''
            doc here
        '''
        def __init__(self,TableName, **kwargs ):
            self.TableName = TableName
            for k,v in kwargs.iteritems():
                setattr(self, k, k)


schema =  {"id" : { "type":"Integer", "primary":"primary_key=True", "unique":"unique = True"},
           "col1" :  { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = True"},
           "col2" :  { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"},
           "col3" :  { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"},
           "col4" :  { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"},
           "CreatedOn" :  { "type":"DateTime", "primary":"", "unique":"unique = False"},
           "UpdatedOn" :  { "type":"DateTime", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"},
                            }


db_create_table('Table1', schema)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to pass `schema` and to unpack it into `**kwargs`, you have to use `**schema`:

```
db_create_table('Table1', **schema)
```

**Explanation:**
The single asterisk form (`*args`) unpacks a sequence to form an argument list, while the double asterisk form (`**kwargs`) unpacks a dict-like object to a keyworded argument list.

Without any asterisk, the given object will directly passed as it is, without any unpacking.

See also [how to use *args and **kwargs in Python](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/).

Comment: Elaborating on this answer, you could also write (simplified): `db_create_table('Table1', id=1, col1=2, col2=3, CreatedOn='2017-09')`

Answer (score 3):

The **kwargs** parameter in the function is capturing keyword arguments; you are passing a single object without unpacking it.

You either need to pass it with **, so it gets unpacked, or add *args to the function definition. For example, look how the function interprets the arguments:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs

func(arg)
func(*arg)
func(*arg, keyword='key')
```

output:

```
(('one', 'two'),)  -- passed as arg, single element
{}
('one', 'two')  -- passed as *arg - object is unpacked
{}
('one', 'two')
{'keyword': 'key'}  -- keyword arg looks like that
```

As you pass positional args with *args, you can pass keyword args with **kwargs when calling the func.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing two *args*, but are only catching *kwargs*.
`schema` is being passed as a positional argument which would be caught by `*args`; if you wanted it to be caught by `**kwargs` you'd have to pass it as *keyword argument:*

```
db_create_table('Table1', schema=schema)
```

Comment: The function has no argument called "schema".  Maybe you meant "kwargs=schema"?  (Even then, I think you need the double asterisk?)

Comment: It doesn't have an argument named `schema`, no. It does have `**kwargs` though, and *any* passed *named argument* is going to go there.

Comment: @deceze actually when passing schema=schema and you're printing the class variables :
    test = db_create_table('Table1', schema = schema)

    print vars(test)
you can see that schema is passed as a string, instead of having the dict keys.

Comment: @user No, what you'll get is an attribute called `schema` with a `dict` as its value. I can only guess at what you're really intending here, you're not saying. @glglgl's probably on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

db_create_table(
'Table1',
id = { "type":"Integer", "primary":"primary_key=True", "unique":"unique = True"},
col1 =  { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = True"},
col2 = { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"},
col3 =  { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"},
col4 =  { "type":"String()", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"},
CreatedOn =  { "type":"DateTime", "primary":"", "unique":"unique = False"},
UpdatedOn = { "type":"DateTime", "primary":"primary_key=False", "unique":"unique = False"}
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).